# Remove spaces from HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a little issue with HTML parser and spaces.

```
<div class="a">
   <div class="b">Foo</div>
   <div class="b">Bar</div>
</div>

.a { width: 500px; }
.b { width: 50%; display:inline-block; }
```

I want to display 2 `div` element in the same line, like this : http://jsfiddle.net/m4xkpLsv/

When I have space between the two `div` elements, my browser inserts a little blank space between them.

The most used solutions are to use HTML comment, delete spaces or set a width of 49%. I don't like theses solutions.

How can I modify my CSS to display theses elements ?

Comment: did you try making the borders and margins to 0?

Comment: Why don't you google ? CSS elemnts side by side ... Many options like float, flexbox, table-cell.

Comment: reset ur elements
*{margin:0;padding:0}

Comment: just add *{ padding:0; margin:0;} http://jsfiddle.net/nwnmq0wr/

Comment: @stackErr Doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Danko Can't use float in this context, but I don't know 'flexbox'. I'm gonna see this.

Comment: Read: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Yes I think it's the white space maybe. Could it be that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637696/how-to-place-div-side-by-side