# Change the div or the contents of the div?

Tags: css, alignment, overflow, space, extra

I'm trying to move the section at the bottom up and to the right of the div that includes the seal, paragraph and news (i.e.: current clients on the right, everything else on the left.)

Currently, I’m using a 60% on the div holding the text in for the left side. I’m guessing that is the contents. I’ve been trying to move "Foo" to the right of the first column.

I’ve fooled with width, padding and margin, align, and quite a few other elements. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

bam

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For your class `entry-content` add the following css: `display: flex;`

This solves the problem.

For more detail check this post: [How to place div side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637696/how-to-place-div-side-by-side)

More details about flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm side-by-side. But it's side by side on mobile now.

Answer (score 0):

you need to float:left both div inside the entry-content div:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <div style="width:60%;float: left;">... more code here ...</div>
    <div style="width:33%;float: left;">... more code here ...</div>
</div>
```