# How to put two different charts next to each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I want to put 2 different highcharts side by side in one page. One is pie chart and the other one is gauge chart. Can you please help me to organize this structure?

Comment: You can use bootstrap if you are familiar with it.

Comment: Please add your current relevant code.

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637696/how-to-place-div-side-by-side) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display).

Comment: Please add your current relevant code..

Answer (score 2):

You can use float. More information about float is available [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp). Try if something like this works.

```
#chart1{
    width: 50%; /* set width to 50% of page width */
    float: left; /* Make the element go to the left */
}

#chart2{
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

Don't forget to add `style="clear: both"` to the next element! Good luck! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

One option is using a flexbox.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.chart1,
.chart2 {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="chart1">chart 1</div>
  <div class="chart2">chart 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add bootstrap classes like this

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Chart 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Chart 2
  </div>
</div>
```