# how to place the element side by side in an html page

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a pomodoro clock and I want to place the controls of the clock to the right of the clock instead of the current position which is down. Right now the html/css code is placing the controls (add time/restart etc) at the bottom of the clock, and I would like to place it to the right. how can I do that? thanks
html

```
<div class="container
  <!-- header title -->
  <div class="title primary-text">
      <h1>Pomodoro Clock</h1>      
  </div>
  <!-- clock / timer goes here -->
  <div class="clock">    
    <div class="timer">
      <h2>Session</h2>
      <h1>23:00</h1>     
    </div>    
  </div>
  <!-- this section for controlling clock -->
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="setTime">
       add time                 
    </div>
    <div class="setTime">
       add time                 
    </div>
    <div class="control">
      play/pause
    </div>
    <div class="control">
      reset
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
  background-color: #545454;
}

.title {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.timer {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 44px;
}

.clock {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.controls {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place div side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637696/how-to-place-div-side-by-side)

Comment: You have a picture of the clock to share?

Comment: Your first div isn't closed properly `<div class="container`

Comment: @Jason why would anyone suggest such nonsense?

Comment: With either `inline-block`, `float`, or `flex-box` styles. What have you already tried?

Comment: this is what I havehttps://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0100

Comment: both element are inline; however, I would like to have the clock completely centered while the controls remains on the right.. https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0100

Comment: @miatech check your link, I just get a "blank canvas"

Comment: sorry, forgot to save. check it again.... https://codepen.io/zentech/pen/eEZdXe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inline-block` for both the `.clock` and `.controls` in order to align them. However, since you want the `.clock` to be centered, you will have to add a bit more code. What I did was create a Container `.clockContainer` in order to then allow for `position: absolute` on your `.controls`. This will remove it form the flow and center your `.clock` while positioning your controls next to it. Then I added some margin to your clock so the 2 elements don't overlap. You can then manipulate the height location of the Controls as you see fit with a `top` value:

```css
body {
  background-color: #545454;
}

.title {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.timer {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 44px;
}

.clock {
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.controls {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.clockContainer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- header title -->
  <div class="title primary-text">
    <h1>Pomodoro Clock</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- clock / timer goes here -->
  <div class="clockContainer">
    <div class="clock">
      <div class="timer">
        <h2>Session</h2>
        <h1>23:00</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- this section for controlling clock -->
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="setTime">
        add time
      </div>
      <div class="setTime">
        add time
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        play/pause
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        reset
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `margin:auto` you can use `float: left` or `display: inline-block`. check updated CSS below..

```
.clock {
  /*margin: auto;*/
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.controls {
  /*margin: auto;*/
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: yes but I would like the clock to be centered and the controls on the right edge of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

to make `.clock` center you can use `display:inline-block;` inside `.clock` and `.controls` with `text-align:center;` inside `.container`

```css
body {
  background-color: #545454;

}

.container{
  text-align:center; 
 }

.title {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.timer {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 44px;
}

.clock {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.controls {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- header title -->
  <div class="title primary-text">
      <h1>Pomodoro Clock</h1>      
  </div>
  <!-- clock / timer goes here -->
  <div class="clock">    
    <div class="timer">
      <h2>Session</h2>
      <h1>23:00</h1>     
    </div>    
  </div>
  <!-- this section for controlling clock -->
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="setTime">
       add time                 
    </div>
    <div class="setTime">
       add time                 
    </div>
    <div class="control">
      play/pause
    </div>
    <div class="control">
      reset
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use this customize code inside `.controls`

`float:right;   margin-right:372px;   margin-top:-202px;` and remove `display:inline-block;` from `.clock`

Comment: in this example the clock is not center. how could I center the clock and still have the controls to the ritht? https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0100