# Where to put the css file when using obelisk

Tags: css, haskell, reflex, reflex-dom, obelisk

I want to make two div's float side by side using Obelisk. For this I used the information from this post, [How to place div side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637696/how-to-place-div-side-by-side) and for this solution classes have to be declared in css. Following the advice of this tutorial (https://github.com/hansroland/reflex-dom-inbits/blob/master/tutorial.md), more specifically the part about mainWidgetWithHead, I put the commands in a different file. The problem is, however, that I can't find where the css-file should be stored in order to get accessed by the program.

I tried to put it in several places within the automatically generated directory by "ob init", but I always end up with an empty css-file when I load it in my browser.

Below you can see a minimal example of the frontend function used in frontend/src/Frontend.hs.

```
frontend :: Frontend (R FrontendRoute)
frontend = Frontend
    { _frontend_head = prerender_ (text "Loading..") headElement
    , _frontend_body = prerender_ (text "Loading...") bodyElement
    }

headElement :: MonadWidget t m => m ()
headElement = do
    el "title" $ text "Title"
    styleSheet "/css/cssTest.css"
        where
            styleSheet link = elAttr "link" (Map.fromList [
                    ("rel", "stylesheet"),
                    ("type", "text/css"),
                    ("href", link)
                ]) $ return ()

bodyElement :: MonadWidget t m => m ()
bodyElement = elClass "div" "container" $ do
    elClass "div" "fixed" $ do
        el "h2" $ text "Button enabled / disabled"
    elClass "div" "flex-item" $ do
        el "h2" $ text "Second paragraph next to it."
```

This error message is consequently given, no matter where I put the css-file:
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/cssTest.css"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store all of the static assets your site needs live in the `static` directory created by `ob init`.  this is especially important for mobile builds.

The other thing you need to do is refer to those assets like the following:

```
styleSheet $ static @"css/cssTest.css"
             ^^^^^^^^
```

assuming you've turned on `TypeApplications`, which is the default in the obelisk skeleton.

Comment: I get the following error using this solution:
Could not deduce (StaticFile "css/cssTest.css")
arising from a use of 'static'. Also {-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-} is used.

Comment: @EmielLanckriet for `StaticFile "foo/bar"`  to be derived, the file needs to be in `static/foo/bar` in your projects root at the time you started `ob run` or when built the project.  If that's still not working, i'll need more information such as your `default.nix`.

Comment: The problem seems to solved by deleting the '/' in "/css/cssTest", using this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57548236/staticfile-error-when-using-ob-and-reflex-to-import-css-file).