# Staticfile error when using Ob and reflex to import CSS-file

Tags: css, haskell, reflex, reflex-dom

I want to make two div's float side by side using Obelisk. For this I already asked this question ([Where to put the css file when using obelisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57500631/where-to-put-the-css-file-when-using-obelisk)). This provided the answer that I should put my stuff in static and add static @filename. However, this approach results in an error.

Below you can see a minimal example of the frontend function used in frontend/src/Frontend.hs.

```
frontend :: Frontend (R FrontendRoute)
frontend = Frontend
    { _frontend_head = prerender_ (text "Loading..") headElement
    , _frontend_body = prerender_ (text "Loading...") bodyElement
    }

headElement :: MonadWidget t m => m ()
headElement = do
    el "title" $ text "Title"
    styleSheet $ static @"/css/cssTest.css"
        where
            styleSheet link = elAttr "link" (Map.fromList [
                    ("rel", "stylesheet"),
                    ("type", "text/css"),
                    ("href", link)
                ]) $ return ()

bodyElement :: MonadWidget t m => m ()
bodyElement = elClass "div" "container" $ do
    elClass "div" "fixed" $ do
        el "h2" $ text "Button enabled / disabled"
    elClass "div" "flex-item" $ do
        el "h2" $ text "Second paragraph next to it."
```

The following error message was given:
Could not deduce (StaticFile "css/cssTest.css") arising from a use of 'static'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me after I removed the leading `/` from `"/css/cssTest.css"` and restarted `ob run` (assuming you placed the file at `static/css/cssTest.css`).