# Inline 2 components in html

Tags: html

I have 2 div components, Is there a way to make it inline. Right now it is coming in 2 lines

```
<div style = "padding-left:10px"><h4 class ="line" >Sev: </h4></div>
<div style = "padding-left:10px"><span class="center"> Weekly : 122</span></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place div side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637696/how-to-place-div-side-by-side)

Comment: Look at CSS Flex. You can align items in rows or columns. Link For [W3Schools link for flex box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_items.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `div` container has a `block` rendering behaviour.
If you want to have a default inline behaviour you may use `span` tag instead, or if you prefer you can use CSS to change the rendering type by adding `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` if you want to have control over the width/height properties.

Your code may look like this :

```
<div style="display: inline-block; padding-left:10px"><h4 class="line" >Sev: </h4></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; padding-left:10px"><span class="center">Weekly : 122</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is lots of way to doing that ,one way is that:
`<div style = "display: inline-flex; padding-left:10px"><h4 class ="line" >Sev: </h4></div>`

`<div style = "display: inline-flex; padding-left:10px"><span class="center"> Weekly : 122</span></div>`
second way:

`<div style = "display: inline-grid; padding-left:10px"><h4 class ="line" >Sev: </h4></div>`

`<div style = "display: inline-grid; padding-left:10px"><span class="center"> Weekly : 122</span></div>`