# bootstrap cards rendered by map function dont show up side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i am using bootstrap and i am trying to display a few cards side  by side but the are displayed under each other, i want the cards to be displayed side by side and then wrap to next line

the code:

```
<div style={{ marginBottom: "100px",  marginTop: "100px" }}>
      <Wrapper id="projects">
        <div className="whiteBg">
          <div className="container2 row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <HeaderInfo>
              <h1 className="font40 extraBold darkblueColor">
                Our Awesome Projects
              </h1>
              <p className="font13">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
                diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                <br />
                labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
              </p>
            </HeaderInfo>

            {projects.map((project, index) => (
              <div className=" textCenter">
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                  <ProjectBox
                    img={urlFor(project.imgUrl)}
                    title="Awesome Project1"
                    text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor."
                    action={() => alert("clicked")}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place div side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637696/how-to-place-div-side-by-side)

Comment: Do you have a link to a Sandbox?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski my question is different my problems cause is that i am using map function

Comment: Your cards columns are not direct child of row. Remove `<div className=" textCenter">` and test it. You can add textCenter class in `col` class

Comment: Why dont you use the `d-flex` class by bootstrap.  A demo link would be helpful.

Comment: *my problems cause is that i am using map function* - the final html and css don't know that you are using `map` or even react. There is no difference between styling something in react or without it