How to put two elements in the same line?
I know this question sound really dumb but I'm new to the coding world. Basically, I want to place a text and a search bar on the same line. How do I do that using html or css?

I tried using the 'display: inline-block' thing that I saw on the internet but that didn't work out.

Welcome to the coding world and Stack Overflow. There are many questions already that have covered your question, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637696/how-to-place-div-side-by-side  It will help you to try out the projected solutions and provide an example of your code if the issue still exists.
