# How to fix text to the left edge of a centered text-box css

Tags: html, css

I have a form that is centered on the page, and the elements are centered in the form. I want the text, however, to align to the left edge of the input boxes in my form. In other words, I want the first letter of the text to start at the left edge of the input box. See code and image below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Log In</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper{
    border:1px solid black;
    max-width:200px;
    max-height:200px;
    display-webkit-box;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#login input{
    display:-webkit-box;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#login span{

}
</style>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<form id="login" action="#" method="POST">
<span>User Names:</span><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<span>Password:</span><br>
<input type="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Image Here]

Comment: text.align : left  ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Left, Center, & Right Align Text on Same Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694062/css-left-center-right-align-text-on-same-line)

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal but it works. It will work for this example as your website uses fixed sizes.

```
#login span{
   margin-left: 17px;
   text-align: left;
}
```

If it's a responsive website, it won't work like this.µ

Image: http://prntscr.com/eaewe0

Comment: I was curious though if there was another positioning technique to use that would be consistent but it's not that big of a deal

Comment: A different way is this, one that gives your input a fixed width, and changes your div to it:

   #login input {
        display: -webkit-box;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 160px;
    }

    #login {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 160px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Log In</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border:1px solid black;
    max-width:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#login input{
    display:-webkit-box;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

    
</style>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<form id="login" action="#" method="POST">
    User Names:&nbsp;<input type="text"><br>
    Password:&nbsp;<input type="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```