# Align 3 divs within row div with text centered

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-alignment

Similar to [How to align 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div), I am trying to align three divs within a parent div. Added complexity is that each div contains an image, text, and a link. I'd like these to be aligned link so:

```
[[LEFT-IMG]    [CENTER-IMG]    [RIGHT-IMG]]
    text           text            text
    link           link            link
```

However, the closest I can get is:

```
[[LEFT-IMG]    [CENTER-IMG]    [RIGHT-IMG]]
 text              text               text
 link              link               link
```

With the text and links mirroring the alignment of the image.

Here my HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 left">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" alt="Thing 1">
      <p>THING 1</p>
      <a href="somedomain.com">somedomain.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 center">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" alt="Thing 2">
      <p>THING 2</p>
      <a href="somedomain.com">somedomain.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 right">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" alt="Thing 3">
      <p>THING 3</p>
      <a href="somedomain.com">somedomain.com</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.row {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

.center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

Note that these are all within a grid div with the following CSS:

```
.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I have a feeling there's something fundamentally wrong with my structure, but I'm not sure what. Very new at this.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Here's a JSFiddle showing current progress. http://jsfiddle.net/ljhennessy/j8jrn719/

The key here is that I'd like the left and right images to be aligned all the way to the red border on either side.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @ljhennessy what do you want ? is it the first example you shown in question?

Comment: Yes. The left and right images must be aligned to their respective sides of the row. The text and link underneath should be aligned under the images.

Comment: @suslov, https://jsfiddle.net/ljhennessy/j8jrn719/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the **class** next to **col-4** class.

**Here's the [Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/qLjchaqs/1/)**.

It will look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" alt="Thing 1">
    <p>PROJECT 1</p>
    <a href="somedomain.com">somedomain.com</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" alt="Thing 2">
    <p>THING 2</p>
    <a href="somedomain.com">somedomain.com</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" alt="Thing 3">
    <p>THING 3</p>
    <a href="somedomain.com">somedomain.com</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

To fit your images with the column just add this code to your css:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I had not used Jsfiddle before, very helpful.

Comment: I created a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ljhennessy/j8jrn719/. The problem (as you can see), is that the images still aren't aligned to the left and right of the row (i.e. the red borders).

Comment: Just add style to your image. width: 100%. I already updated the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Just change   text-allign property to center for    .left and .right