# Image gallery display/aligning

Tags: html, css, image

I want these 3 divs (or should i make a single one) to aling one photo to the left, one centered and the other one to the left corner of the container.
Right now i have this:
[image: The problem]

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
                    <div class="foto"></div>
                    <div class="foto"></div>
                    <div class="foto"></div>
            </div> <!--Gallery END -->
```

CSS:

```
.foto {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: #0BB5FF;
}
#gallery {
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

Thanks for answers!

Comment: This question seems to be similar to this one- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div

Comment: use "left: 70%;" something according to your wish

Comment: try `width:32.9%;` in `.foto` and remove the height value

Answer (score 0):

Apply something like:

```
margin-top: 5em; 
margin-left: 16em;
```

You can change your value according to your page !