# Align and centre divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a web page. I am trying to centre and align my divs properly (the animated company logos).

I need them to sit next to each other instead of on top of each other, with spacing in between to fit the page.

This might make things more clear:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="Style.css" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="container">
            <h1>
 <a href="a">My Interactive Webpage </a>
</h1>
                     <h1>
 <a href="a">Career Page </a>
</h1>

<style> 
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="Information Page.html">Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="Game Page.html">Games</a></li>
  <li><a href="Career Page.html">Career</a></li>
</ul>      
        </header>      
        <div id="container">     
        <head>
<center>

<p><font face="verdana" color="green">Welcome to my Career Page! 
I am passionate about all aspects of computer games development especially programming and games design. Since an early age I have played and experienced a wide range of platforms and games and retain my love for this form of entertainment. One of my favourite games of all time is Oblivion, on the PC and developed by Bethesda, it played brilliantly, was graphically superb and had a perfect soundtrack. I would love to be involved in developing a game of that quality for the current generation of platforms as well as PC. A computer games programme that gives me a strong foundation in computer science is ideal. It gives me the fundamental skills and knowledge for adapting to this rapidly changing and evolving games industry.
Below are some of the companies I would dream of working for.   Please click the text to be taken to the respective homepage of each company. 
</font></p>
</center>                   
           </div>                  
        <div class="tilt pic">  
<style> 

#rcorners3 {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/AkIPWeF.png);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 
}
</style>

<a href="http://eu.blizzard.com/en-gb/">
    <font color="white"><p id="rcorners3">BLIZZARD ENTERTAINMENT</p></font>
 </a>
    </div>

    <div class="tilt pic">    
        <style> 
#rcorners2 {   
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Mouf1lw.png);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;    
}
</style>

<a href="http://www.naughtydog.com/"> <font color="white"><p id="rcorners2">NAUGHTY DOG</p></font>
 </a>
    </div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<div class="tilt pic">    
        <style> 
#rcorners4 {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/pFeIHdd.png);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 
}
</style>

<a href="https://www.ubisoft.com/en-GB/">
    <font color="white"><p id="rcorners4">UBISOFT</p></font>
 </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>

</body>

</html>

 </div>      
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>   
   </html>
```

Comment: You have a lot of errors on your HTML. For one thing, a HTML document is only supposed to have one `<html>` element, and everything else sits in there. If you make sure your HTML syntax is correct, the chances of your document looking the same in different browsers are much greater.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently going through my code trying to delete my novice errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already there are a lot of errors, I really tried to go through it, but it actually would take quite a while...

Here is an first attempt of removing some errors: https://jsfiddle.net/6qfq1c7g/

However, you should not use this code since there are still many mistakes.

Please consider to read something about classes and the html basic structure which should be something like http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Do not use `<html>` or `<head>` or `<body>` twice.

You can of course use `<style>` tags within your html but you should at least put them all together so you are not switching between html and css all the time. Best practice would be creating a separate file for your css as you already implement in your head (style.css).

Use classes for same elements. Your "company" elements are basically all the same, so you should do something like

```
.company {
   border: 1px solid #333;
   border-radius: 5px;
   // and so on ....
}
```

For the background then you can use specific ids or even classes again

```
.blizzard {
  background-color: url('blizzard.jpg');
}

.ubisoft {
   background-color: url('ubisoft.jpg');
}
```

This will clean up your code a lot.

Actual response:

To align your 3 elements every element needs the css style

```
display: inline-block;
```

I also recommend to give

```
vertical-align: top;
```

so that everything is aligned on the same height. To center it then again you should add

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

And the outer wrapping element should have

```
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned there is a lot of unnecessary repetition in your code that can be cleaned up but to answer your question I'd suggest using a table, specifically a table row with its **`width` set to 100%** to format your images how you want them like so:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td>
  <div class="tilt pic">
    <a href="http://eu.blizzard.com/en-gb/">
      <font color="white"><p id="rcorners3">BLIZZARD ENTERTAINMENT</p></font>
    </a>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="tilt pic">
    <a href="http://www.naughtydog.com/"> <font color="white"><p id="rcorners2">NAUGHTY DOG</p></font>
    </a>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="tilt pic">
    <a href="https://www.ubisoft.com/en-GB/">
      <font color="white"><p id="rcorners4">UBISOFT</p></font>
    </a>
  </div>
</td>
```

And lastly in order to center your images within their respective cells you need to add the following to each of their ids:

```
#rcorners3 {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
...
}

#rcorners2 {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  ...
}

#rcorners4 {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  ...
}
```

This makes ensures that the spacing on each side of the element is equal regardless of how much space is actually available.

See working example - http://jsfiddle.net/ddwqkm5t/1/

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="Style.css" />

               <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="container">
            <h1>
 <a href="a">My Interactive Webpage </a>
</h1>
                     <h1>
 <a href="a">Career Page </a>
</h1>

<style> 
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="Information Page.html">Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="Game Page.html">Games</a></li>
  <li><a href="Career Page.html">Career</a></li>
</ul>

        </header>

        <div id="container">


        <head>

<center>

<p><font face="verdana" color="green">Welcome to my Career Page! 
I am passionate about all aspects of computer games development especially programming and games design. Since an early age I have played and experienced a wide range of platforms and games and retain my love for this form of entertainment. One of my favourite games of all time is Oblivion, on the PC and developed by Bethesda, it played brilliantly, was graphically superb and had a perfect soundtrack. I would love to be involved in developing a game of that quality for the current generation of platforms as well as PC. A computer games programme that gives me a strong foundation in computer science is ideal. It gives me the fundamental skills and knowledge for adapting to this rapidly changing and evolving games industry.
Below are some of the companies I would dream of working for.   Please click the text to be taken to the respective homepage of each company. 
</font></p>

</center>            

           </div> 


        <div class="tilt pic" style="float:left; padding:10px;">

<style> 

#rcorners3 {

    border-radius: 25px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/AkIPWeF.png);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 

}
</style>



<a href="http://eu.blizzard.com/en-gb/">
    <font color="white"><p id="rcorners3">BLIZZARD ENTERTAINMENT</p></font>
 </a>
    </div>




    <div class="tilt pic" style="float:left; padding:10px;">    
        <style> 
#rcorners2 {

    border-radius: 25px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Mouf1lw.png);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 

}
</style>

<a href="http://www.naughtydog.com/"> <font color="white"><p id="rcorners2">NAUGHTY DOG</p></font>
 </a>
    </div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<div class="tilt pic" style="float:left; padding:10px;">    
        <style> 
#rcorners4 {

    border-radius: 25px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/pFeIHdd.png);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 

}
</style>



<a href="https://www.ubisoft.com/en-GB/">
    <font color="white"><p id="rcorners4">UBISOFT</p></font>
 </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>





</body>


</html>

 </div>   


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: The least you could have done was correct some of the errors in the OP's code.

Comment: Hello, thank you. But I am not sure this worked.   I will keep trying.