# Equally distribute 3 divs within a div - without float

Tags: css, alignment, centering

I have been reading widely about this but haven't been able to solve it to my satisfaction.

I have a div (`<section>`) that contains one `<p>` and 3 `<div>`s. I would like to distribute the 3 divs equally in one line so that the left border of the 1st div is on the left border of the document (`<body>`) and the the right border of the 3rd div on the right border of the document.

I don't want to use float because the backround-color would vanish.

I have tried flex but `justify-content` did not yield the expected outcome.

Here's the code on [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/codusi/embed?output).

Thank you!

Comment: Wrap the divs and flex the wrapper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div)

Comment: Thanks Michael_B, I that post has a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div/32122011#32122011 which explains how to do it an also why `flex` is the most effective solution.

Comment: @johann_ka, you're welcome. And that post you reference was my answer to that question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on the container, and set the width of the three div elements to take up one third (or as close as we can get) of its container. The container must have a set width (either pixel or percentage) for it to work.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 33.333333%;
}
#container div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content1">
    I'm some content. Regardless of the width of this div, the content will move to the next line and stay within the div instead of overflowing.
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/P8z2H80.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
    I'm some more content. Regardless of the width of this div, the content will move to the next line and stay within the div instead of overflowing.
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NfnBZAI.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="content3">
    I'm even more content. Regardless of the width of this div, the content will move to the next line and stay within the div instead of overflowing.
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/W8M37N2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```