# Having trouble placing 2 divs side by side in wrapper

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having trouble putting 2 divs side by side within a wrapper. I've read existing questions and articles on how to place 2 divs side by side; it seems very simple, just define width and float:left for both divs. However, I can't get it to work!

Any help would be appreciated, thank you! :)

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Toppoki/7pazLwLs/23/

HTML:

```
<div class="child1">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="blurb">
</div>
<div class="form">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.child1 {
background:#082a46;
margin:0;
}

.wrapper {
width:970px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.blurb {
color: #fff;
width:200px;
height:400px;
float:left;
}

.form{
background-color:#9c0b0e;
width:100px;
height:400px;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Simple and easy: [**Align divs side-by-side with flexbox**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32122011/3597276)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already working for the snippet you showed. I just put a background color on the `div.form` so you could see.

In your example on jsfiddle the `div.blurb` lacks the `float:left`, and there is a lot of things that can get you confused.

Start taking off some of the placeholder text and unnecessary elements and styles. Start making it very simple, indent it well, and add the styles one at a time. It will eventually work.

```css
.child1 {
  background:#082a46;
  margin:0;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:970px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.blurb {
  color: #fff;
  width:200px;
  background-color: blue;
  height:400px;
  float:left;
}

.form{
  background-color:#9c0b0e;
  width:100px;
  height:400px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="child1">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="blurb">
    </div>
    <div class="form">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also place 2 divs side by side using `display:inline-block` on the two divs.

(If you want it responsive, define the width of the child with `%` and not pixels.)

```css
.child1 {
  background:#082a46;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.blurb {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
  width:200px;
  height:400px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.form{
  background-color:#9c0b0e;
  width:100px;
  height:400px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="child1">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="blurb"></div>
    <div class="form"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```