# aligning elements in their containers and the containers on the line

Tags: html, css, django-forms

I've got several elements that I am trying to group together and then center them on page like so:

```
                                         |
                                         |
              Username:                  |                 
              ________________           |                 IMG 1
              Password:                  |                 
              ________________           |                 IMG 2
                  login                  |
                                         |
                                         |
```

I don't want Username and password centered, I still want to those to be at the very left side of the input boxes.

Right now it looks something like this:

```
                                         |
 Username                              IM|G 2  
                                         |                 
         _______________                 |                 IMG 1
         _______________             Pass|word:                 
                                         |                 
                  login                  |
                                         |
                                         |
```

I've got IMG 1, the login button and the vertical line in a good spot but the form is just all over the place.  I've tried playing around with a lot of different things to get the rest of the login form and IMG 2 in the right spot but I am stuck.  Here is the basic layout of my html file:

```
<div id="center-wrapper">
    <div id="img1">
        <img src="img1.png" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="img2">
        <img src="img2.png" />
    </div>

    <div id="line"></div>

    <form id="form-wrapper" action="/login/" method="post" style="width:40%;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <br>
        {% if field.errors %}
            <div class="form-group has-error">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">
                {{ field.label }}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {{ field|attr:"class:form-control" }}
                    <span class="help-block">
                        {% for error in  field.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {{ field|attr:"class:form-control" }}
                    {% if field.help_text %}
                        <p class="help-block"><small>{{ field.help_text }}</small></p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Log In">{% trans "Log In" %}</button><br>
            <br>Don't have an account? <a href="/signup/">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My button is inside my form so I am not sure why that one is being centered properly and the rest of the form is not.  Also, the `<br>` is not putting IMG 2 under IMG 1.  My CSS is this:

```
#center-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
}

#form-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
}

#img1 {
    height: 220px;
    width: 274px;
    background: none;
    z-index: 30;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
}

#img2 {
    height: 85px;
    width: 274px;
    background: none;
    z-index: 30;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#line {
    height: 305px;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #8a8a8a;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 30;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I don't think my question is very hard, but I have been struggling over getting this format right for so long and I just want some suggestions!  I am using Django forms, which are pretty tricky to format (formatting them with widget-tweaks), but I don't think that should matter for moving its position around.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mp6oquxz/9/

Comment: this may give you some places to start: https://jsfiddle.net/exh3s8vz/1/

Comment: @RachelGallen I've added all the html for my form, as I said Django forms are tricky to format, so that might be the source of some of my problems

Comment: @ryantdecker that helps a little but ideally I would like to have the form, line and image not overlap when you shrink the window

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith yours is also very helpful but I would like for the images to stay the same size when you enlarge/shrink the window size

Comment: Have you looked at @DaniP answer bellow

Comment: Flexbox is well-suited for aligning elements on a line... http://stackoverflow.com/a/32122011/3597276

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please avoid the use of `absolute` positions for this kind of layouts that will break your view at some point.

I suggest the use of other CSS methods. Check this snippet examples if you have more questions you can ask:

**Display - Table**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#center-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
#center-wrapper > div {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
#center-wrapper > div:first-child {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
#form-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
}
label,
input {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="center-wrapper">
  <div>
    <form id="form-wrapper">
      <label>User</label>
      <input type="text">
      <label>Pass</label>
      <input type="text">
      <button type="submit" value="Log In">Log In</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Inline-block**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#center-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#center-wrapper > div {
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
#center-wrapper > div.line {
  width:2%;
  height:100%;
  background:purple;
}
#form-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
}
label,
input {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="center-wrapper">
  <div>
    <form id="form-wrapper">
      <label>User</label>
      <input type="text">
      <label>Pass</label>
      <input type="text">
      <button type="submit" value="Log In">Log In</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

<sub>**Note** : Other methods like flex will work also, but this here will give you an idea</sub>

Comment: I really like these results!  How would I go about making the red line shorter?

Comment: Nevermind I got it: `#center-wrapper{ height: 40%; padding-top: 300px; }`

Comment: Scratch that I made `padding-top: 25%` and now it looks perfect!

Comment: @Catherine glad to help U ... sorry for the late answer

Answer (score 2):

No need to use position just use like that,
HTML

```
<form id="form-wrapper">
    <label for="username">
        Username:
        <input type="text" name="username">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label for="password">
        Password:
        <input type="text" name="password">
    </label>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" value="Log In">Login</button>
</form>

<div id="imgs">
    <img src="img1.png" alt="Img 1" />
    <br>
    <img src="img2.png" alt="Img 2" />
</div>
```

I Just change some code of yours.
CSS

```
#center-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#form-wrapper{
  border-right: 2px dashed gray;
}
#form-wrapper, #imgs {
  width: 49.5%;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
  #form-wrapper input{
  border: none;
}
#form-wrapper label{
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
```