# CSS div's are not separating

Tags: html, css

I have a problem aligning my div's side by side...

Here is an image how it should look:

[image]

This is the code for the main structure:

```
<div id="AttackDiv">
    <div id="ImageDiv">
    </div>
    <div id="ContentDiv">
    </div>
    <div id="SkillDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

The "ImageDiv" is where the picutre is located. It takes up `120px`.
The "ContentDiv" is where the text is inside and the "SkillDiv" is where the 3 other black boxes are inside.

This is my CSS:

```
#ImageDiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
}

#ContentDiv {
    height: 60%;
    background-color: green;
}

#SkillDiv {
    height: 40%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Shows up this:

[image]

The problem is when I am trying to add those black boxes which you can see above in the image. Here is how it looks:

[image]

If I remove the white background color, you can see that somehow the Div's aren't aligning properly. They are kinda like running in each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs are block elements by default and, in the normal flow, they occupy 100% width of their container. So, naturally, div elements will stack vertically forming a column.

To make them align side-by-side consider these options:

- apply `float: left` to all divs you want to display in a row
- define the divs as `display: inline-block`

OR, for a very simple and efficient solution, just use flexbox:

- [Aligning Three Divs Horizontally Using Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32122011/3597276)

Also, when working with floats, it helps to be familiar with ***clearfix*** methods:

- [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)
- [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/211383/3597276)
- [Clearing Floats: An Overview of Different clearfix Methods](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)

Answer (score 1):

Put the stuff on the right side into its own div container and then float it to the right.

If I understood you right, this should be it:

HTML

```
<div id="AttackDiv">
    <div id="ImageDiv">left
    </div>
    <div id="RightSide">
      <div id="ContentDiv">right1
      </div>
      <div id="SkillDiv">right2
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#ImageDiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: 120px;
    float: left;    
    background-color: white;
}

#ContentDiv {
    height: 60%;
    background-color: green;
}

#SkillDiv {
    height: 40%;
    background-color: blue;

}

#RightSide {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
 }
```

You can look at it here: https://jsfiddle.net/mxcqyjos/4/