# Fit 3 elements in the same line

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements in `HTML` as follows:

```css
.navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
.sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">Navigation</nav>
<section class="content">Section</section>
<aside class="sidebar">Aside</aside>
```

This should fit in the 100% width of the container (`<body>` or any other `<div>`). However the `.sidebar` is being dropped to the next line. I tried to setup border, margin and padding to 0 with the `!important` definition (just to test) but the result is the same. How can I fit this 3 elements in the same line keeping the `width` property?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: [Add `display: flex` to the container](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32122011/3597276).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone else mentioned, the issue is that when using `display: inline-block`, white-space - even between element tags - is accounted for in rendering. There are a few ways to get around this.

1. Setting `display: table-cell` rather than `inline-block` can work in a simple situation like this; just note that it prevents the blocks from wrapping
2. You can set `font-size:0;` on the parent to get rid of the whitespace, but you'll have to reset it on all the direct children.
3. Unless you have to support pre-IE10 browsers, I'd recommend flexbox here! You may need to add some browser prefixes, but the base would look like this (name your parent element something better than 'parent', though!):

   ```
   .parent { display: flex; }
   .navigation, .sidebar { flex: 1 }
   .content { flex: 2 }
   ```

   What that snippet is saying is "make the children fit, and make `.content` twice as big as the other two".

Answer (score 0):

Even though you removed the padding, margin, and border, inline elements are actually sensitive to white space in the code itself. Remove that and they line up:

```css
.navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
.sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">Navigation</nav><section class="content">Section</section><aside class="sidebar">Aside</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using display inline-block, it takes the space in your code as a character(space), so, you have 100% + the space required for 2 characters, you could keep the formatting of your code and ¨remove¨ the space between your containers setting the font-size of the parent to 0

```css
.container{
    font-size:0; 
}
.container *{
    font-size:12px;
}
.navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
.sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<nav class="navigation">Navigation</nav>
<section class="content">Section</section>
<aside class="sidebar">Aside</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: this option + j08691 and @kyojimaru are the three most common options to remove spaces in containers when you´re using display: inline-block

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using the style of `display:inline-block` which will recognize and create a space between element if your code have a space (either space, or new line), so what you need to do is just remove the space like answered by [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39070714/2674662)

Or you can either remove the spacing by using a comment like this one

```css
.navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
.sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">Navigation</nav><!--
--><section class="content">Section</section><!--
--><aside class="sidebar">Aside</aside>
```

Or other way around is using the style `margin` like in this example, the `background` is used to visualize the size of the the `inline-block` element only

```css
.navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 -0.4em 0 0; background: red;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 -0.4em 0 0; background: green;
}
.sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 -0.4em 0 0; background: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">Navigation</nav>
<section class="content">Section</section>
<aside class="sidebar">Aside</aside>
```