# Why does CSS Flexbox not properly size the right-most container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

After having had troubles trying to display three containers in a row with the middle one being centered on the page and the side ones being of a fixed width I came across [the CSS Flexbox model](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), mentioned [in a Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div).

Using `display: flex` instead of `float: left` or displaying the containers as `inline-box` whilst messing with `margin` seems to be working quite well, with way fewer lines of code.

However, I ran into an issue with *flexbox* that I can't seem to solve on my own:

I want a container `#menubar` to hold three containers in a row: `#logo`, `nav` and `#search`.

```
<div id="menubar">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="search"></div>
</div>
```

The `#logo`-container as well as the `#search`-container are of a fixed size (`width: 80px`, `height: 80px`). One should be placed at the very left side of the `#menubar`-container and one should be placed at the very right.

The `nav`-container should be centered within the middle of the `#menubar`-container. Basically the positioning *is working* and I get the desired layout:

```
[#logo left]    [nav centered]    [#search right]
```

However, for some reason the `#logo`-container is being displayed at the specified dimension of `80px width * 80px height` while the `#search`-container is being displayed at `79px width * 80px height`, even through the CSS looks like:

```
header div#menubar div#logo {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: orange;
}

header div#menubar div#search {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

To confirm I made a screenshot and zoomed in with Photoshop, selecting the container to view its dimensions.

[image: Layout missing pixel]

I can't figure out why the `#search`-container is missing one pixel in width.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/as387bhy/2/) with the HTML and CSS I am using.

- Am I using *flexbox* correctly?
- How do I fix it so both side-containers are 80x80 pixel in dimensions?

Comment: Add `flex-shrink: 0` to both `#logo` and `#search`. See section ***The `flex-shrink` factor*** here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34355447/3597276

Comment: I've just tried adding `flex-shrink: 0`, viewing the page in Mozilla Firefox still shows 79px in width for the `#search` container: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/as387bhy/3/)

Comment: In your [revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/as387bhy/3/), both `#search` and `#logo` are 80x80 (computed) in FF, Chrome, Edge and IE11.

Comment: This is odd. I even cleared Firefox' cache and I still get 79px for `#search`. Also tried with Chrome, still 79px for me. Could my screen resolution of 1920x1200 or anything else be the cause?

Comment: I don't think screen resolution is an issue. I can't reproduce the problem. Getting 80x80 all around.

Comment: Holy cow, it must be "Lightshot", which I was using, to cut off the right-most column of pixels when taking a screenshot. I just viewed the container in the Inspector tool (CTRL+SHIFT+I) and it shows the 80px width :) Thank you for the help, `flex-shrink: 0` does the job even though I go with the "more proper" solution of using `flex: 0 0 80px`.

Comment: Glad you found your solution. In the link I referred in my first comment, it discusses the advantage of using `flex: 0 0 80px`. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I using flexbox correctly?

**Yes and no**

Instead of `width` you should, ideally, be using the `flex`shorthand property combining, `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`.

```
header div#menubar div#logo {
    flex: 0 0 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Alternatively, you can ensure that the element doesn't shrink by using `width` AND the `flex-shrink` value of 0

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
body {
  background-color: #dfe3e5;
}
header div#top {
  height: 22px;
  /*background-image: url('../img/colorbar.png');
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;*/
  background-color: gray;
}
header div#menubar {
  background-color: #1c2227;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
header div#menubar div#logo {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: orange;
}
header div#menubar nav {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkred;
}
header div#menubar nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
header div#menubar nav ul li a {
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Raleway', "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header div#menubar nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: orange;
}
header div#menubar div#search {
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="menubar">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="search"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Then you get the right result

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information, I'm going with your primary suggestion of using `flex: 0 0 80px`. Seems to be displaying fine now!