# div do not align as row using display: flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to align three div on the same row but div only display one by row, as if I was using column. Any idea on what's my error ?

Do not hesitate to tell me if you think the error could come somehow from the 'header.php' which is the only other part of my work so far. I'll post HTML and CSS of it here if asked to.

```css
body {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  font-family: 'robotolight';
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  jusitify-content: space-around;
}
.mydiv {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px #999999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px #999999;
  -o-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px #999999;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px #999999;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="mydiv">
    first div left
  </div>

  <div class="mydiv">
    second div center
  </div>

  <div class="mydiv">
    third div right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to style a class called container (`.container`) but "container" is an ID in your HTML. The CSS should be `#container`.

Comment: Once you get the class/ID syntax corrected, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32122011/3597276

Comment: that's right. it works now thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You havn't a `.container` element, you have a `#container` element.
2. It's `justify-content` and not `jusitify-content`.

Example:

```css
.container {
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: .5rem;
  width: 210px;
}
.box {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```