# centering one column of iframes

Tags: html, iframe, centering

I have 6 graphs and I want to display them in 2 rows and 3 columns. For each row, I aligned one graph left, one center, and one right. The code worked except for the center-aligned graphs. What am I doing wrong?

My code is below.
Please view the snippet "full-screen" to see the alignment.

```html
<iframe width="432" height="258" align="left" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/1?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Relative+Humidity+%28RH%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Relative+Humidity"></iframe>
<iframe width="432" height="258" style="text-align:center" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/2?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Air+Temperature+%28AT%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Air+Temperature"></iframe>
<iframe width="432" height="258" align="right" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/3?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=pH+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=pH"></iframe>
<br>
<iframe width="432" height="258" align="left" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/4?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Light+Intensity+%28LI%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Light+Intensity"></iframe>
<iframe width="432" height="258" style="text-align:center" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/5?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Water+Temperature+%28WT%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Water+Temperature+%28WT%29"></iframe>
<iframe width="432" height="258" align="right" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/6?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Electrical+Conductivity+%28EC%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Electrical+Conductivity+%28EC%29"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

One method of configuring the three columns is to [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) the left graph left, the right graph right, and to center the third column by using [auto margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Values). This requires changing the order of the graphs in your HTML code so that the center column comes third after the two floated columns.

For inline elements (like [`iframes`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#edef-IFRAME)), the "auto" margin value cannot be calculated. So I made the graphs block elements.

For more reference on this method, see [How to align 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div)

```css
iframe {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  display: block;
}
.graph-left {
  float: left;
  border-color: red;
}
.graph-right {
  float: right;
  border-color: blue;
}
.graph-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="graph-left" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/1?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Relative+Humidity+%28RH%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Relative+Humidity"></iframe>
<iframe class="graph-right" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/3?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=pH+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=pH"></iframe>
<iframe class="graph-center" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/2?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Air+Temperature+%28AT%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Air+Temperature"></iframe>
<br>
<iframe class="graph-left" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/4?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Light+Intensity+%28LI%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Light+Intensity"></iframe>
<iframe class="graph-right" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/6?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Electrical+Conductivity+%28EC%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Electrical+Conductivity+%28EC%29"></iframe>
<iframe class="graph-center" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/5?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Water+Temperature+%28WT%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Water+Temperature+%28WT%29"></iframe>
```

Another method is to use a [CSS multi-column layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts). You may want to check the [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) of this feature. At the time of this post, [prefixes are required](http://shouldiprefix.com/#multicolumn) for maximum browser compatibility.

```css
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  display: block;
}
.graph_row {
  
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  
  -webkit-column-count: 3;  /* Ch, Saf, And, BB  */
     -moz-column-count: 3;  /* Fx */
          column-count: 3;  /* IE 10, Op 11.1+ */
  
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
     -moz-column-gap: 1em;
          column-gap: 1em;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="graph_row">
  <iframe class="graph" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/1?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Relative+Humidity+%28RH%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Relative+Humidity"></iframe>
  <iframe class="graph graph-right" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/3?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=pH+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=pH"></iframe>
  <iframe class="graph graph-center" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/2?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Air+Temperature+%28AT%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Air+Temperature"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="graph_row">
  <iframe class="graph graph-left" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/4?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Light+Intensity+%28LI%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Light+Intensity"></iframe>
  <iframe class="graph graph-right" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/6?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Electrical+Conductivity+%28EC%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Electrical+Conductivity+%28EC%29"></iframe>
  <iframe class="graph graph-center" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/219280/charts/5?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=10&title=Water+Temperature+%28WT%29+Time+Series+Chart&type=line&xaxis=Time&yaxis=Water+Temperature+%28WT%29"></iframe>
</div>
```