# How set two divs on the sides of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with setting elements in a div. How can I set to display the number of elements on the page on the left and the search on the right

Here is a part of the code:

```
<div class="header-size-section">
    <div class="lable-size-section">
        <select class="form-control size-list" id="table-size-list" name="table-size-list" onchange="tableSizeChanged(this)">
            <option>25</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
            <option>all</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="header-search-section">
        <span class="table-search-list">Search: </span>
        <input type="text" class="search-table" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8v7gm5j1/2/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g96oz5wL/

Comment: just add `justify-content: space-between` to `.header-size-section`

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the:
`.header-size-section`(change display: flex to display: block) and `.header-size-section>.header-search-section`(you missed dots)

```css
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed),
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tbody>tr>th,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tfoot>tr>th,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>thead>tr>td,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tbody>tr>td,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tfoot>tr>td {
  padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;
}

.header-size-section {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.size-list {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.table-search-list {
  margin: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 6px;
}

.search-table {
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.header-search-section,
.lable-size-section {
  display: inline-table;
}

.header-size-section>.header-search-section {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header-size-section justify-content-between">
  <div class="lable-size-section">
    <select class="form-control size-list" id="table-size-list" name="table-size-list" onchange="tableSizeChanged(this)">
            <option>25</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
            <option>all</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="header-search-section">
    <span class="table-search-list">Search: </span>
    <input type="text" class="search-table" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. There's no need to use floats anymore. Also, using display: table-cell and inline-table. Quite a lot of properties for such a simple task.

Answer (score 1):

You are using bootstrap. Use bootstrap class `justify-content-between`. This ensures that the elements within that block have equivalent space between them.

Now, as there are only two element, you get complete space in center.

You can also use `justify-content-around`.

```css
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed),
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tbody>tr>th,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tfoot>tr>th,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>thead>tr>td,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tbody>tr>td,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tfoot>tr>td {
  padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;
}

.header-size-section {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.size-list {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.table-search-list {
  margin: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 6px;
}

.search-table {
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.header-search-section,
.lable-size-section {
  display: inline-table;
}

header-size-section>header-search-section {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header-size-section justify-content-between">
  <div class="lable-size-section">
    <select class="form-control size-list" id="table-size-list" name="table-size-list" onchange="tableSizeChanged(this)">
            <option>25</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
            <option>all</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="header-search-section">
    <span class="table-search-list">Search: </span>
    <input type="text" class="search-table" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This is an example with `justify-content-around`.

```css
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed),
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tbody>tr>th,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tfoot>tr>th,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>thead>tr>td,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tbody>tr>td,
.bootstrap-table .table:not(.table-condensed)>tfoot>tr>td {
  padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;
}

.header-size-section {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.size-list {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.table-search-list {
  margin: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 6px;
}

.search-table {
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.header-search-section,
.lable-size-section {
  display: inline-table;
}

header-size-section>header-search-section {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header-size-section justify-content-around">
  <div class="lable-size-section">
    <select class="form-control size-list" id="table-size-list" name="table-size-list" onchange="tableSizeChanged(this)">
            <option>25</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
            <option>all</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="header-search-section">
    <span class="table-search-list">Search: </span>
    <input type="text" class="search-table" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this and remove the rest of the css:

```
.header-size-section {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.lable-size-section {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.search-table {
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```