# Center a divs within div?

Tags: css

I'm trying to center three div boxes within one large one. A grid is going to be 3 wide and auto height.

```css
.t-box920g {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background: #121212;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px dotted #363636;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.i-box {
  width: 279px;
  height: 209px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  text-align: justify;
}

.i-pbox {
  width: 276px;
  height: 206px;
  background: #121212;
  border: solid 2px #ffffff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: justify;
}

#i-imageconstrain {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 276px;
  max-height: 206px;
  min-width: 276px;
  min-height: 206px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="t-box920g">
  <div class="i-box">
    <div class="i-pbox">
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/gallery/sample1.jpg">
        <img id="i-imageconstrain" src="images/gallery/sample1.jpg" border="0" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="i-box">
    <div class="i-pbox">
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/gallery/sample2.jpg">
        <img id="i-imageconstrain" src="images/gallery/sample2.jpg" border="0" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="i-box">
    <div class="i-pbox">
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/gallery/sample3.jpg">
        <img id="i-imageconstrain" src="images/gallery/sample3.jpg" border="0" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works as planned EXCEPT for the content of t-box920g being left justified. I've tried a lot of combos and none have worked so far. Got a suggestion? I'll let you know if I tried already.

Tried text-align, align-content, align-items, margin: auto in combinations for all css.

I expect it to be center justified with nice even spacing. Actually is all left.

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox.
You can read more about how to use it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and [here](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) if you like to learn through games.

This question was asked and answered on Stack Owerflow already more than once, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div).

```css
.t-box920g {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.t-box920g .i-box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 32%;
}
```

```html
<div class="t-box920g">
  <div class="i-box">
    <div class="i-pbox">
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/gallery/sample1.jpg">
        <img id="i-imageconstrain" src="images/gallery/sample1.jpg" border="0" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="i-box">
    <div class="i-pbox">
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/gallery/sample2.jpg">
        <img id="i-imageconstrain" src="images/gallery/sample2.jpg" border="0" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="i-box">
    <div class="i-pbox">
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/gallery/sample3.jpg">
        <img id="i-imageconstrain" src="images/gallery/sample3.jpg" border="0" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```