# Align 3 divs inside another div and vertically center them

Tags: html, css

I have a `div-container` (colored blue) where I want to put 3 `div-element`s (colored red).

`div-element`s have to be vertically aligned (I just used `margin-top: 10%;` for that) and first one has to be left, second centered and third right in the same line. To achieve that I have made 3 `id`s `#left`, `#center` and `#right`.

However it all gets messed up when I put those `id`s in. First one is aligned allright, second one is centered but `margin-top: 10%;` doesn't affect it anymore and the third one is on the right side but in the new line.

I have tried putting `display: inline-block;` in my `div-element` class. This aligns right element correctly but messes up the center one.

Why is this happening and how do I solve this?

It is quite obvious that I have tried [How to align 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div) since I have used exact same `id`s, but the above mentioned solution doesn't work here and I have specifically asked why my `margin-top: 10%;` in `.div-element` doesn't affect center div

```css
.div-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.div-element {
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

#center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#left {
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-container">
  <div class="div-element" id="left">Left</div>
  <div class="div-element" id="center">Center</div>
  <div class="div-element" id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using flexbox for this:

```css
.div-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.div-element {
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-container">
  <div class="div-element">Left</div>
  <div class="div-element">Center</div>
  <div class="div-element">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way for me to do this would be to use CSS grid to position the columns

```
 <style>
       .div-container {
      display:grid;
      grid-template-column: 3, 1fr;
       width: 50%;
      }
   </style>
```