# How do I align the div tags so that they display in one line

Tags: html, css

Div tag that wraps the additional div tags.

```
<div class="shoes-box">
                        <div>
                        <img class="shoe-image" src="pictures/jordan1.jpg" alt="Jordan Ones">
                        <p>Jordan 1's</p>
                        <p class="sizes-availabel">Sizes sizes-availabel</p>
                        <ol class="sizes-availabel-ol">
                            <li>size 6 UK</li>
                            <li>size 7 UK</li>
                            <li>size 8 UK</li>
                        </ol>
                        </div>
```

Picture two that should be aligned to the right of the other shoe

```
                        <div>
                            <img class="shoe-image" src="pictures/jordan3.jpg" alt="Jordan Threes">
                            <p>Jordan 3's</p>
                            <p class="sizes-availabel">Sizes sizes-availabel</p>
                            <ol class="sizes-availabel-ol">
                                <li>size 6 UK</li>
                                <li>size 7 UK</li>
                                <li>size 8 UK</li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: Have you looked at display inline-block, or possibly grid or flex, depending on your exact use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div)

Answer (score 1):

I specified the two divs as div1 @ div2, then applied the following CSS Styling.

```
.div1{
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: beige;
}
.div2{
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
    background: beige;

}
```

Here is the example:

```css
.div1{
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: beige;
}
.div2{
  width: 49%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background: beige;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
ol {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.shoe-image {
  height: 10vh;
  width: auto;
    display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
      <img class="shoe-image" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.u7eQmPSGhB63KXY3hBYbUAHaE3?pid=ImgDet&rs=1" alt="Jordan Ones">
      <p>Jordan 1's</p>
      <p class="sizes-availabel">Sizes sizes-availabel</p>
      <ol class="sizes-availabel-ol">
         <li>size 6 UK</li>
         <li>size 7 UK</li>
         <li>size 8 UK</li>
      </ol>
   </div>
   <div class="div2">
      <img class="shoe-image" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.hjh2LiIQqnvLOdfQp_dqLgHaE6?pid=ImgDet&rs=1" alt="Jordan Threes">
      <p>Jordan 3's</p>
      <p class="sizes-availabel">Sizes sizes-availabel</p>
      <ol class="sizes-availabel-ol">
         <li>size 6 UK</li>
         <li>size 7 UK</li>
         <li>size 8 UK</li>
      </ol>
   </div>
</div>
```